# How to solve "502 internal error - server connection terminated" error?

Tags: apt, software-installation

When I try to install VirtualBox through Ubuntu Software Center it fails with the following errors:

```
Failed to fetch http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gsoap/libgsoap3_2.8.12-1_amd64.deb 502  internal error - server connection terminated [IP:
202.158.214.106 80] Failed to fetch http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libs/libsdl1.2/libsdl1.2debian_1.2.15-5ubuntu2_amd64.deb 502  internal error - server connection terminated [IP:
202.158.214.106 80] Failed to fetch http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/multiverse/v/virtualbox/virtualbox_4.2.16-dfsg-3_amd64.deb 502  internal error - server connection terminated [IP:
202.158.214.106 80] Failed to fetch http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/multiverse/v/virtualbox/virtualbox-dkms_4.2.16-dfsg-3_all.deb 502  internal error - server connection terminated [IP:
202.158.214.106 80] Failed to fetch http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/multiverse/v/virtualbox/virtualbox-qt_4.2.16-dfsg-3_amd64.deb 502  internal error - server connection terminated [IP:
202.158.214.106 80] Failed to fetch http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/fakeroot/fakeroot_1.20-1_amd64.deb 502  internal error - server connection terminated [IP:
202.158.214.106 80]
```

So, I download the deb for 13.10 from here, https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads, and drag and drop it on the Software Center icon.  Same result.

Why would that be?  Has anyone else had difficulty with this?  It has been going on for about 4 hours, so I doubt that it's site congestion.

Comment: did you try to install the .deb file by running `sudo dpkg -i /path/filename.deb`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mirror you are using seems to create the problem.Just changing the server should solve the problem.But if you want ***to hit two birds in a go, follow these steps***.

- Go to **System settings** > **Software & updates**(this can have a slightly different name) > **Download from** >**other**
- Select **Select Best server**
- Wait for the output and choose the server which suites you the best(generally the first one is best)

Alternately, you may just **choose Main server**, but note that **it is very busy**.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be an issue with the mirror you are using.

Go to **System Settings** > **Software & Updates** and set **Download from:** to a different server.

Answer (score 2):

I'm also having the same issue right now and switched to the main servers and it worked.

Go to Settings -> Software & Updates -> Select "Main server" instead of server for Australia.

I'm thinking it must be a temporary issue, so you'll probably want to change that back in a day or two but that got it to work for me.